# Exact sequence induces exact sequences for free parts and torsion parts?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $A$ be a PID and consider the exact sequence of finitely generately modules over$A$:

$$0\longrightarrow M' \overset{f}{\longrightarrow}M\overset{g}{\longrightarrow}M''\longrightarrow 0 \tag{1}.$$

Denote the free part and torsion part by $F(M)$ etc. and $T(M)$ etc. respectively. Does the above exact sequence induces ones on the free parts and torsion parts?

Comment: But you can tensor the exact sequence with $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence
$$
0\rightarrow \mathbb Z\xrightarrow{n} \mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z_n\rightarrow 0
$$
is exact in $\mathbb Z\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$. Passng to torsion we have
$$
0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow \mathbb Z_n\rightarrow 0
$$
which is not exact. Passing to free parts we have
$$
0\rightarrow\mathbb Z\xrightarrow{n}\mathbb Z\rightarrow 0\rightarrow 0
$$
which is also not exact.

Comment: Then what about the free parts? Actually need this part. And in fact your example in not what I need: $\mathbb Q$ is not f.g.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!

Comment: @ Brian Fitzpatrick Do you know the so-called Grothendieck group? In Atiyah and Macdonald, chapter 7, exercise 26, iii), I had shown $K(A)$ is generated by the element $\gamma (A)$, but cannot prove it has infinite order.

Comment: Perhaps further inquiries would be better off as new questions.

Comment: OK, I will do this!